# how to protect reading file

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have multiple threads reading a file. The file path contains a symbolic link which gets updated periodically by a daemon on background (not a java application).

For example, consider this file path `/home/user/me/data/current/file.out`, `current` is a symbolic link to an actual directory which contains the file, `file.out`, and `current` is getting update periodically by a daemon.

Java threads only read the file (do not write to the file). How do I make sure threads are safe to read the file? I am thinking about a locking mechanism but I can not make the daemon to put a lock when it updates the symbolic link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using lock in an another way, create a dummy file x.lock if the current thread has access to x.lock let it read the file. Modify your demon process to first get access to x.lock file and then update. If it doesn't have the lock wait until the process gets access to x.lock file. Hope this gives you a pointer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a lock. You either cannot open the file when the link is being updated (unless it is done in an [atomic manner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6786) by the daemon), or you can. Once the Java application has opened the file for reading (possibly after several tries if the link is not updated in an atomic manner), it doesn't matter if the (symbolic link to the) file is moved, deleted or renamed - the Java application will still be able to read the file since Linux keeps the originally opened file (handle/inode) available to the Java application.

This is also why sometimes deleting a file does not free up disk space: some process is still using it. Only when all open file handles for the deleted file are closed, the disk space used by the deleted file will become available (free).